# Error while sending Image for face matching to AWS Rekognition on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-rekognition

I'm getting an error while sending Image for recognition to AWS Rekognition. 
This is the code which I use:

```
        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(facePicture.byteCount)
        facePicture.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
        val image = Image().withBytes(byteBuffer)

        val searchFacesByImageResult = rekognitionClient.searchFacesByImage(
            SearchFacesByImageRequest()
                .withCollectionId(collectionId)
                .withImage(image)
                .withMaxFaces(1)
                .withFaceMatchThreshold(88F)
        )
```

And this is an error:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]' at 'image.bytes' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1 (Service: AmazonRekognition; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 70a3f05c-8166-11e9-a1cb-fbae8cf4359b)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient.invoke(AmazonRekognitionClient.java:3006)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient.searchFacesByImage(AmazonRekognitionClient.java:238
```

Exception looks like `ByteBuffer` is empty, I have debugged and checked that ByteBuffer is valid and is not empty

Answer (score 2):

It appeared the problem was in Image format, I was using RAW BMP format, the format in which Bitmap is represented in memory. But Amazon doesn't support this format, it is stated in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/limits.html)

> Amazon Rekognition supports the PNG and JPEG image formats. That is, the images you provide as input to various API operations, such as DetectLabels and IndexFaces must be in one of the supported formats.

To fix this I have changed my code to this:

```
     val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
     facePicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
     val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(stream.toByteArray())
     val image = Image().withBytes(byteBuffer)
```